# elasticdump can't import data from file

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried import data from json file. Use command like this: 
`elasticdump --input=2016-1-1-2016-7-31-2.json --output=http://localhost:9200/` And format like this: https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/blob/master/test/seeds.json 
My backup file has few indexes. But when I start command which I wrote above - got result like this:

`Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:44 GMT | starting dump
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:44 GMT | got 100 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:44 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:44 GMT | got 291 objects from source file (offset: 100)
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:44 GMT | sent 291 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:44 GMT | got 292 objects from source file (offset: 391)
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:45 GMT | sent 292 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:36:45 GMT | got 293 objects from source file (offset: 683)`

If I set index name in URL or through --output-index={INDEX} - all data from file go to that index with separating on types.

I will be grateful for the help!

Answer (score 1):

in your elasticdump commandline , try with type argument `--type=data` and `indexName` e.g. `elasticdump --input=2016-1-1-2016-7-31-2.json --output=http://localhost:9200/myIndex --type=data`

Answer (score 0):

With Docker you can do tne next:

```
docker run --name es-dump --rm -ti elasticdump/elasticsearch-dump \
    --input=./2016-1-1-2016-7-31-2.json \
    --output=http://localhost:9200/2016-1-1-2016-7-31-2 \
    --type=data \
    --limit=10000
```